# Volley library error in android studio using json object

Tags: java, android

i created a delete address class

code

```
public class DeleteAddress {
    boolean result = false;
    String addressid;

    public boolean delAddress(Context context, final int id){

        addressid = Integer.toString(id);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_DELETE_ADDRESS,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                                result = false;
                            }
                            else {
                                result = true;
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        System.out.println(error.getMessage());
                        result = false;
                    }
                }

        ){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", addressid);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestHandler.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);

        return result;
    }
}
```

the code for address adapter

```
public class AddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressHolder>{
    private ArrayList<Address> dataList;
    Context context;
    int id;
    
    DeleteAddress deleteAddress = new DeleteAddress();

    public AddressAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Address> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList= list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AddressHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new AddressHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddressHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(dataList.get(position));
        id = holder.getAddressId(dataList.get(position));


        holder.deleteAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this address?");
                alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                //dummy
                                arg0.cancel();
                                //System.out.println(id);                   working fine
                                if(deleteAddress.delAddress(context, id)){
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Address record deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                else {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Some error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }

                                Intent i = new Intent(context, AddressListActivity.class);
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                context.startActivity(i);
                            }
                        });

                alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int i) {
                        arg0.cancel();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

so let me explain what i am trying to do.
I have made a layout that displays address in Address activity and i am displaying data from mysql php backend. this activity is working fine. i added two items in the recycler view using which we can edit and delete a particular address record. edit button is working fine but delete isn't working.
If i click on delete button i get toast message some error occured. but if i test the button 2-3 times i get the same message but the record gets deleted.
web services are working fine so no issues with that.
there are no errors in logcat.

I don't know what is going on. can someone help. need any more portion of code i can update it...

EDIT:
i have caught the error. in the deleteaddress class for some reason the value of result variable is not getting updated inside the String request method. i tried to print the message from the web service in the logcat and it shows that address is getting deleted and i checked the database is also getting updated but still i get the toast message that some error occured.

Comment: I am seeing any error in your source code. But, I need little info that 
Is toast taking few time to show?

Comment: no it doesn't take time

Comment: hey man i made an edit can u check??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onResponse(String response)` is asynchron method

you updates `result` in callback function. The method `delAddress` returns always false. (it returns `true` in second execution, because `result` was later updated)

your code should be changed like:

make new interface

```
public interface CallbackClass {
    void onSuccess();
    void onFail(String message);
}
```

change

```
public boolean delAddress(Context context, final int id)
```

to

```
public void delAddress(Context context, final int id, CallbackClass callback)
```

then

```
result = false;
```

could be like

```
callback.fail("error");
```

and

```
result = true;
```

could be like

```
callback.success();
```

and at least

```
if(deleteAddress.delAddress(context, id)){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Address record deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Some error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

to

```
deleteAddress.delAddress(context, id, new CallbackClass(){
    void onSuccess(){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Address record deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    void onFail(String message){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Some error occurred!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: man i didnt get it can u like write the complete code for the delete address class

Comment: @Mr_Sharma, what is not clear? i have wrote, what parts of code you should update in your code. You shouldn't return something in `delAddress` and work instead with Callback. Create `CallbackClass` as own class and not inner class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's error in your delete class. I am not getting issue in adapter.

OK! Let's check Logcat.

```
System.out.println(error.getMessage());
```

Or,

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

And, enter a logcat on following source code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                            result = false;
                            Log.d("Error","Some error occured");
                        }
                        else {
                            result = true;
                        }
```

Then, check in Logcat where you are getting error.
Then, comment below.
As you said there's no error occurred in Logcat. So, you have check `verbose`.

Edited/Solution :

```
if(jsonObject.getBoolean("error")){
                            result = false;
                        }
                        else {
                            result = true;
                        }
```

You wrote that you are getting boolean(.getBoolean).
But, you put String value inside Quotation mark

`jsonObject.getBoolean("error")`

You have to write `true` or `false` instead of that `"error"` string

I hope it will help you

Comment: theres no error and the database is getting updated which means volley is working fine but i checked the value of result variable and it is just not getting updated even if the code is executed

Comment: at the beginning of the delete address class i defined boolean result= false and this value is not changing and i dont know why

Comment: @Mr_Sharma You said that you are getting datas from server, aren't you?
If you are getting datas than I got the issue on that class

Comment: $response['error'] = false; 
$response['message'] = "Address record deleted!";

Comment: this is what i am sending from server. error is like one of the key in json object

Comment: @Mr_Sharma check what value are you getting on `jsonObject.getBoolean("error")` after clicking button once.